# How to tell if a React functional component has been rendered in code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to add some logging to see how much time it takes to render a functional component in React. The tricky part to me is how to actually tell when the component has been rendered. By "rendered", it means the user can see it in the front end (all parts in that component should be displayed). I am trying to use **useEffect** to achieve this, as it can tell when the component is mounted.

The code is something like below:

```
function showComponent() {
   console.log('start rendering....start timer');
   console.log(new Date().getTime());
   
   setStoreViewState('foobar');
}

observer(function Component() {
   React.useEffect(() => {
     console.log('rendering complete....stop timer');
     console.log(new Date().getTime());
 }, []);
   ......
   const thingsToShow = getStoreViewState();
   return (<div>{thingsToShow}</div>)
}
```

I am wondering if this is an accurate way to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of tools that you can use to optimize performance: I Think using something like the Profiler in chrome extension from React Dev Tools might be what you are looking for? This extension will show you how long it takes to render and if it re-renders and such.

Comment: No, I am not looking for perf optimization. I want to know how to tell in code when a component has finished rendering, so I am not looing for tools just in code.

Comment: You could use the Profile Api: https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html. With this you can get performance in code.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, the useEffect with no dependency means that it has finished rendering.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

`Also, don’t forget that React defers running useEffect until after the browser has painted, so doing extra work is less of a problem.`

The quote above is from the docs.